# Error when portrait and landscape the App

Tags: android

I have an error on my App while trying to rotate the device To test my app on portrait mode. My app consist of 4 editTexts and 4 textviews , the app supporting 2 language , Arabic and English , so when my phone is English language the app works fine in portrait mode.
But when i tried to change the language in arabic and when i put the device in portrait mode , the app displays in landscape mode.
I have written command for displaying landscape mode. But why when i change the language into arabic the app displays as landscape mode>???

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:launchMode = "singleInstance"

    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".personal_info.Personal_Info_Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>





</application>
```

**Layout.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_Personal_Info"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id = "@+id/Military_Num_TextView"
        android:textSize="@dimen/Title_Size"
        android:text="@string/personal_data"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/Table_row_Margin_Top">
        <TextView
            android:id = "@+id/Military_Num"
            android:text="@string/military_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/TxtView_margin_right"
            android:textSize="@dimen/Personal_Information_Text_Size"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <EditText

            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/TxtView_margin_right"
            android:background="@drawable/editbox_background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/EditText_Height"
            />
    </TableRow>




    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/Table_row_Margin_Top">
        <TextView
            android:id = "@+id/Name"
            android:text="@string/Name"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/TxtView_margin_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/Personal_Information_Text_Size"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText

            android:inputType="text"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/TxtView_margin_right"
            android:background="@drawable/editbox_background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/EditText_Height"
            />
    </TableRow>









    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/Table_row_Margin_Top">
        <TextView
            android:id = "@+id/Rank"
            android:text="@string/Rank"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/TxtView_margin_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/Personal_Information_Text_Size"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText

            android:inputType="text"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/TxtView_margin_right"
            android:background="@drawable/editbox_background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/EditText_Height"
            />
    </TableRow>








    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/Table_row_Margin_Top">
        <TextView
            android:id = "@+id/Date_of_Birth"
            android:text="@string/Date_of_Birth"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/TxtView_margin_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/Personal_Information_Text_Size"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:inputType="date"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/TxtView_margin_right"
            android:background="@drawable/editbox_background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/EditText_Height"
            />
    </TableRow>







    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/Table_row_Margin_Top">
        <TextView
            android:id = "@+id/Phone_Number"
            android:text="@string/Phone_Number"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/TxtView_margin_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/Personal_Information_Text_Size"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText

            android:inputType="phone"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/TxtView_margin_right"
            android:background="@drawable/editbox_background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/EditText_Height"
            />
    </TableRow>







    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/Table_row_Margin_Top">
        <TextView
            android:id = "@+id/E-mail"
            android:text="@string/E_mail"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/TxtView_margin_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/Personal_Information_Text_Size"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText

            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/TxtView_margin_right"
            android:background="@drawable/editbox_background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/EditText_Height"
            />
    </TableRow>
```

**java**

```
    package com.example.computer.completionofthestudy.personal_info;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.computer.completionofthestudy.R;

public class Personal_Info_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.personal_info);

}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.lang_ch:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "SignatureView is empty: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }






}









</TableLayout>
```

2 pictures of the error:-

English lang : https://ibb.co/buvud8
Arabic lang: https://ibb.co/eWtQko

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following to your Activity tag in AndroidManifest.xml :

```
android:configChanges="locale"
```

But use it carefully go through [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes#HandlingTheChange), Its quick and dirty fix. Otherwise you should handle it through overriding **onConfigurationChanged** method in your activity

Comment: does your app language is chnaged on orientation change ?

Comment: when its english it works fine, but when i change the local lang to arabic and open app again , it rotates as u sow in picture two.

Comment: seems issue with your locale code, orientation change affects app locale, not other way round. can you paste your code where your are changing locale of app, also code regarding config change if any.

Comment: try adding android:supportsRtl="false" in your application tag in manifest.

Comment: sorry brother i am unable to follow up why is that happening.